# How to set relative position with wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

i have a wxpython listbox and its height set to -1, which would mean that it would automatically set to the height of the window. Is there a way to leave a 200px at the end of the window?

So basicilly i guess what i am looking for is (window_height - 200), to leave a 200 space.

-1 would go the full window height.

Thanks.

EDIT: I cant seem to get it to work with my code;

```
COLORS = ["red", "blue", "black", "yellow", "green"]
NUMBERS = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
image=[];

import random
import wx
class images_tab(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        ## random test useless  t = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "This is a PageOne object", (20,20))
        self.listBox = wx.ListBox(self, size=(200, -1), choices=image, style=wx.LB_SINGLE)
#        self.button = wx.Button(self, label="Something else here? Maybe!")
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer.Add(self.listBox, proportion=0, flag=wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, border=5)
#        self.sizer.Add(self.button, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)



class MyNotebook(wx.Notebook):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Notebook.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.notebook = MyNotebook(self, size=(220, -1))
        Images__tab = images_tab(self.notebook)
        # add the pages to the notebook with the label to show on the tab
        self.notebook.AddPage(Images__tab, "Click here to lookat pictures")

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer.Add(self.notebook, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        #self.sizer.Add(self.button, proportion=0) #with button
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.SetTitle("Python: Pictures")
        self.panel = MyPanel(self)
        app.frame = wx.Frame(parent=None, id=-1, size=(300,400))
        self.Show()


app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None, size=(600, 400))
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in a sizer: mysizer.Add(myListBox, 0, wx.BOTTOM, 200)

EDIT: Or you could use wx.GetDisplaySize() to get the width and height of the window, subtract 200 from the height and use that to set the size of the listbox.

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt seem to work in my example, i have added code to the description. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just changed the following line to: "self.sizer.Add(self.listBox, proportion=0, flag=wx.BOTTOM | wx.EXPAND, border=100)" and it seemed to work for me. Maybe I'm not understanding what you want. You could use a spacer in your sizer too.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted however now it is changing the original canvas rectangle location.

Comment: Adding a spacer to your sizer may be what you want then

Comment: Do you know how to Add a border to a specific element, such as wx.LEFT
"self.sizer.Add(self.listBox, proportion=0, flag=wx.BOTTOM | wx.LEFT, border=100)" would give a 100 border to both wx.BOTTOM and wx.LEFT, is there a way to give 100 border to wx.BOTTOM and a 50 border to wx.LEFT?

Comment: Sure. Put one sizer inside another. So something like: self.secondSizer.Add(self.sizer, 0, wx.LEFT, 50)